# Two persons A and B throw a die. Who wins given the below conditions?

Tags: probability

Two persons $A$ and $B$ throw a (fair) dice (six-faced cube with faces numbered from $1$ to $6$) alternately, starting
with $A$. The first person to get an outcome different from the previous one by the opponent wins. The
probability that $B$ wins is ?

Comment: Your attempt...?

Answer (score 3):

Draw a tree and notice that, by periodicity, the probability that B wins is :

$$P_B=\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} \times(\frac{5}{6}+...)$$

So we can express this probability as the limit of an increasing sequence bounded by 1, so it converges, and we get :

$$P_B=\frac{5}{6}+\frac{1}{36}P_B \leftrightarrow P_B=\frac{6}{7}$$

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't get how the probability that B wins is 5/6 + 1/6 × 1/6 × (5/6+...)? The solution I have goes the exact same way @trueblueanil's first answer goes; but I'm having trouble understanding the above.

Answer (score 0):

Two other way to look at it , with $P(B) = p$, are:

**(a)**

$p = \dfrac56 + \dfrac16\dfrac16\dfrac56 + ........$

which is a $G.P.$ with $a = \dfrac56, r = \dfrac 1{36}\;\; and\;\; S\infty = \dfrac{a}{1-r} = \dfrac {5/6}{1-1/36} = \dfrac67$

**(b)**

Probabilities of $B$ and $A$ winning at their *first opportunities* are $\dfrac5{6}$ and $\dfrac5{36}$ respectively,
and the *ratio* repeats in cycles,

thus odds in favor of $B = 30:5$, and $p = \dfrac{30}{35} = \dfrac67$